# IE8 check in developer tools which files have been loaded

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

How does one check in IE8 developer tools which files the browser has downloaded for the specific page (page contents, js files, css files etc,), can't find the list/correct option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a link from Microsoft documentation for the developer tools details.

Answer (score -1):

Found it... Wasn't very obvious.

[image]